# Using Typing and Mypy with Descriptors

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, python-descriptors

I have looked at a few SO posts and github issues related to using Typing with descriptors but I have not been able to get my issue resolved.

I have wrapper classes and I want to define properties as descriptos that can get and "cast" properties of an internal data structure.

```
class DataDescriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, name: str, type_):
        self.name = name
        self.type_ = type_

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        if not instance:
            raise AttributeError("this descriptor is for instances only")
        value = getattr(instance._data, self.name)
        return self.type_(value)


class City(object):
    zip_code: str = DataDescriptor("zip_code", str)
    # mypy: Incompatible types in assignment

    population: float = DataDescriptor("population", float)
    # mypy: Incompatible types in assignment

    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data


class InternalData:
    # Will be consumed through city wrapper
    def __init__(self):
        self.zip_code = "12345-1234"
        self.population = "12345"
        self.population = "12345"


data = InternalData()
city = City(data)
assert city.zip_code == "12345-1234"
assert city.population == 12345.0
```

I thought I might be able to use TypeVar but I haven't been able to wrap my head around it.

This is what I have tried - I thought I could dynamically describe that the descriptor will take a "type", and this type is also the type `__get__` will return. Am I on the right track?

```
from typing import TypeVar, Type
T = TypeVar("T")


class DataDescriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, name: str, type_: Type[T]):
        self.name = name
        self.type_ = type_

    def __get__(self, instance, cls) -> T:
        if not instance:
            raise AttributeError("this descriptor is for instances only")
        value = getattr(instance._data, self.name)
        return self.type_(value)
        # Too many arguments for "object"mypy(error)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your solution was close. In order to get it fully working, you needed to make just three more changes:

1. Make your entire DataDescriptor class generic, not just its methods.

   When you use a TypeVar within your constructor and method signatures just by itself, what you're ending up doing is making each *method* independently generic. This means whatever value is bound to `__init__`'s T will actually end up being completely independent from whatever value of T `__get__` will return!

   This is the complete opposite of what you want: you want the value of `T` between your different methods to be exactly the same.

   To fix, have DataDescriptor inherit from `Generic[T]`. (At runtime, this will mostly be the same as inheriting from `object`.)
2. Within City, either get rid of the type annotations for your two fields or annotate them as being of type `DataDescriptor[str]` and `DataDescriptor[float]` respectively.

   Basically, what's happening here is that your fields themselves are actually DataDescriptor objects, and need to be annotated as such. Later, when you actually try using your `city.zip_code` and `city.population` fields, mypy will realize that those fields are descriptors, and make their types be whatever the return type of your `__get__` method is.

   This behavior corresponds to what happens at runtime: your attributes are *actually* descriptors, and you get back either a float or a str only when you try *accessing* those attributes.
3. Within the signature for `DataDescriptor.__init__`, change `Type[T]` to either `Callable[[str], T]`, `Callable[[Any], T]`, or `Callable[[...], T]`.

   Basically, the reason why doing `Type[T]` doesn't work is that mypy doesn't know exactly what kind of `Type[...]` object you might be giving your descriptor. For example, what would happen if you tried doing `foo = DataDescriptor('foo', object)`? This would make `__get__` end up calling `object("some value")`, which would crash at runtime.

   So instead, let's have your DataDescriptor accept any kind of converter function. Depending on what you want, you could have your converter function accept only a string (`Callable[[str], T]`), any single argument of any arbitrary type (`Callable[[Any], T]`), or literally any number of arguments of any arbitrary type (`Callable[..., T]`).

Putting these all together, your final example will look like this:

```py
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Any, Callable

T = TypeVar('T')

class DataDescriptor(Generic[T]):
    # Note: I renamed `type_` to `converter` because I think that better
    # reflects what this argument can now do.
    def __init__(self, name: str, converter: Callable[[str], T]) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.converter = converter

    def __get__(self, instance: Any, cls: Any) -> T:
        if not instance:
            raise AttributeError("this descriptor is for instances only")
        value = getattr(instance._data, self.name)
        return self.converter(value)


class City(object):
    # Note that 'str' and 'float' are still valid converters -- their
    # constructors can both accept a single str argument.
    #
    # I also personally prefer omitting type hints on fields unless
    # necessary: I think it looks cleaner that way.
    zip_code = DataDescriptor("zip_code", str)
    population = DataDescriptor("population", float)

    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data


class InternalData:
    def __init__(self):
        self.zip_code = "12345-1234"
        self.population = "12345"
        self.population = "12345"


data = InternalData()
city = City(data)

# reveal_type is a special pseudo-function that mypy understands:
# it'll make mypy print out the type of whatever expression you give it.
reveal_type(city.zip_code)    # Revealed type is 'str'
reveal_type(city.population)  # Revealed type is 'float'
```